# Best practice when joining two main non linked tables (no FK) by static id

Tags: sql, database, join

I would like to combine data from two "main" tables in one single SQL query which I can not join via parent-child key link because non exists

Let's say I have **main_table** and (for the lack of any better name) **main_table2**

I can do this

```
SELECT * FROM main_table mt
   LEFT JOIN optional_data ON mt.id = od.fk_mt_id
   LEFT JOIN main_table mt2 on mt2.id=$some_id
```

$some_id is in variable defined in my code

I'm looking for your advice if the above is accepted as best practice of joining **main_table2**  which does not have any relationship with **main_table** or **optional_data**?

Are there any negative consequences when such join via variable occurs?

Do you think such requirement is a sign of incorrectly structured database?

Comment: It's not clear what your definition of join is in this context. Please provide a few rows of sample data and the expected result so we can help you.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you intend:

```
SELECT *
FROM main_table mt LEFT JOIN
     optional_data od
     ON mt.id = od.fk_mt_id LEFT JOIN
     main_table mt2 
     ON mt2.id = $some_id;
```

(I added a table alias for `od`.)

Then I can only comment on the structure of the query.

1. Do not use `SELECT *`.  By definition, you have columns with duplicated names because the same table appears twice in the `FROM`.
2. Do not munge query strings with constant values.  `$some_id` should be passed in as a parameter.
3. You might be able to accomplish what you want in some other way, but your question doesn't provide enough information.